# Video file not recognized in android studio

Tags: android-studio, format, mp4, android-videoview

I added a file named 'testingClip' of mp4 format in a directory i made named 'raw' under 'res',it keeps on showing this error message saying it doesn't recognize the file type.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use any capital letter in resource file name Change your `testingClip.mp4` to `testingclip.mp4`

resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore and The resource name must start with a letter.